# How to access an object's parameter named as date

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I know it's probably simple, but I'm receiving this object from NASA API and I'm not being able to access the object parameter named "2020-01-02".

I'm receiving the "error parsing" message if I try to access like Object.near_earth_objects."2020-01-02" or Object.near_earth_objects.2020-01-02, or any other variation of it, which makes sense for sure.

```
{
"links": {
"next": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-01-03&end_date=2020-01-03&detailed=false&api_key=A8QOwQlPLCc2EYkcNhYxj1SZKIHh83v6tkp55y7e",
"prev": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-01-01&end_date=2020-01-01&detailed=false&api_key=A8QOwQlPLCc2EYkcNhYxj1SZKIHh83v6tkp55y7e",
"self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-01-02&end_date=2020-01-02&detailed=false&api_key=A8QOwQlPLCc2EYkcNhYxj1SZKIHh83v6tkp55y7e"
},
"element_count": 13,
"near_earth_objects": {
  "2020-01-02": [other parameters...] 
}
```

Comment: Need to use a [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Comment: Access it like this `Object.near_earth_objects["2020-01-02"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

You can not access like that... I see two reasons for that, one you are starting the property name with a number and you use '-' in the middles as well.

That way you must you [] to access the property, like this:

near_earth_objects['2020-01-02']

Answer (score 1):

This snippet gives you access to value inside `"2020-01-02"` which currently `"test"`

```
let data = {
    "links": {
        "next": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-01-03&end_date=2020-01-03&detailed=false&api_key=A8QOwQlPLCc2EYkcNhYxj1SZKIHh83v6tkp55y7e",
        "prev": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-01-01&end_date=2020-01-01&detailed=false&api_key=A8QOwQlPLCc2EYkcNhYxj1SZKIHh83v6tkp55y7e",
        "self": "http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-01-02&end_date=2020-01-02&detailed=false&api_key=A8QOwQlPLCc2EYkcNhYxj1SZKIHh83v6tkp55y7e"
    },
    "element_count": 13,
    "near_earth_objects": {
        "2020-01-02": "test"
    }
};

console.log(data.near_earth_objects["2020-01-02"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var k = {
  "element_count": 13,
  "near_earth_objects": {
    "2020-01-02": [{
      "one": "one",
      "two" : "two"
    }]
  }
}
var a = k.near_earth_objects["2020-01-02"]
console.log(a)
```

And you will get the content of "2020-01-02" like this :

```
[ { one: 'one', two: 'two' } ]
```